# Passing session between two lua files

Tags: lua, freeswitch

I want to call another lua script from my main script say like
  session:execute("lua","/path/somefile.lua "..somearg1.." "..somearg2..)
its working fine and somefile.lua is executing but suppose i also want to  use session there i.e. i am accessing a database in somefile.lua and want to speak a query result in somefile.lua by using session. (session:speak(queryResult)).

i also tried sending session as one of argument
session:execute("lua","/path/somefile.lua "..session)
but it gives a error "attempt to concatenate global 'session' (a userdata value)"
any advise..??

code of first lua file

```
session:answer();
session:setAutoHangup(false);
session:set_tts_params("flite","kal");
callerId = session:getVariable("caller_id_number");
session:execute("lua ","/etc/freeswitch/scripts/checkbal.lua "..callerId.." "..session);
session:destroy();
```

code for 2nd lua file

```
callerId=argv[1];
session=argv[2];
luasql = require "luasql.postgres";
env=assert(luasql:postgres());
con=assert(env:connect("mydb","postgres","password","127.0.0.1","5432"));
cur=assert(con:execute("select balance from bal where number='"..callerId.."'"));  
session:set_tts_params("flite","kal");
row=cur:fetch({},"a");
res=row.balance;
session:speak(res);
```

Comment: A piece of code might help

Comment: @W.B. as you can see this is a simple code. i just need a way to do this thing. i also tried using session:transfer() and excuting 2nd lua file from dialplan extension but its also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rig your second file to be a module that returns a function or a table of functions. Here is an example that has second file return a "speak" function that you can then re-use as many times as desired:

Code of first Lua file:

```
session:answer()
session:setAutoHangup(false)
session:set_tts_params("flite","kal")
callerId = session:getVariable("caller_id_number")
speak = require 'checkbal'
speak(session, callerId)
-- session:execute("lua ","/etc/freeswitch/scripts/checkbal.lua "..callerId.." "..session)
session:destroy()
```

Code for 2nd Lua file:

```
luasql = require "luasql.postgres"

local env=assert(luasql:postgres())
local con=assert(env:connect("mydb","postgres","password","127.0.0.1","5432"))

local function speak(session, callerId)
    local cur = assert(con:execute("select balance from bal where number='"..callerId.."'"))
    session:set_tts_params("flite","kal")
    row=cur:fetch({},"a")
    res=row.balance
    session:speak(res)
end

return speak
```

Note: this is Lua: no need for semicolons.

I would consider making "session" an object (table with methods) with a "speak" method, but this is going beyond scope of this question and is not necessary, may just lead to more maintainable code later.